# Gevent task with endless loop seems to block every other task aswell

Tags: python, python-3.x, gevent, slack-api, greenlets

I'm quite new to Gevent/Greenlet and have gone through the tutorials.
I would like to run a bot for each registered team.

```
for bot in self.bots:
    events.append(gevent.spawn(bot.start))
gevent.joinall(events)
```

The interesting part is that if I don't use a `while true` loop, I get the `bot_id` of both bots shown in the console.

```
def start(self):
        while True:
            for reply in self.slack_client.rtm_read():
                self.input(reply)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            logger.info("Log:{0}".format(self.bot_id))
```

But as soon as I use a endless loop, I can only see one bot's id being displayed. It seems as if the other task is waiting for this one to finish, which makes no sense.  I thought that `gevent.joinall` would run both in parallel.

any advice on this please?

**UPDATE**

For the record, I had to add `gevent.sleep(0.1)` on the last line of while loop to make this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Gevent introduction](http://sdiehl.github.io/gevent-tutorial/):

> Only one greenlet is ever running at any given time.

Basically I think that what you are looking for is parallelism not asynchronous operations. Maybe a better fit would be to use the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Thanks, in fact I found out that `joinall()` is concurrency ran at the same time. Which is not parallelism.  Hence I added `gevent..sleep(0.1)` at the end of the loop and now it's working just fine.  What is your opinion, would that scale for this purpose? Because multiprocessing takes a lot of resources (memory-wise)

Comment: @Houman it should work pretty well if that input function is simple enough. But you should test the limit for the number of bots per machine.